# if / else not working correctly. What could be the problem?

Tags: php, if-statement

I get the numbers I need to get with 'GET' correctly.  I've assigned value of  to variables. But it makes absurd results when it makes a comparison of '>' or '<'. I can't get the right result.

```
<?php // SEPETE ÜRÜN EKLEME ***************************

session_start();

ob_start();

if(isset($_GET['urunKodu'])){
    $eldeki_stok = $_GET['stock'];
    $istenen_miktar = $_GET['amount'];

    if($istenen_miktar < $eldeki_stok){ **// This section does not work correctly.**
        echo '<script language="javascript">';    
        echo 'alert("transaction accepted !")';

        echo '</script>';
        …
        header("Refresh: 0; url=http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.php");    
    }elseif($eldeki_stok < $istenen_miktar){ **// This section does not work correctly.**
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("invalid operation")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}else{      
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: you should var_dump your vars to make sure they're what you expect

Comment: Please, to improve you'r question, can you print eldeki_stok and istenen_miktar variable? and type? and share it...maybe its type diff or empty...

Comment: Make debugging using var_dump function. if the number is a string, use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: I print. number is coming. no problem but the code is not working properly.

Comment: So you have said that you are seeing the numbers so please do a var_dump as ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs asked.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue was your use of the `if` and `else`, that's aside the value data type

```
<?php
// SEPETE ÜRÜN EKLEME ***************************

session_start();

ob_start();

if (isset($_GET['urunKodu'])) {
    $eldeki_stok = intval($_GET['stock']);
    $istenen_miktar = intval($_GET['amount']);

    if ($istenen_miktar < $eldeki_stok) { // This section does not work correctly.**
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("transaction accepted !")';

        echo '</script>';
        …
        header("Refresh: 0; url=http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx.php");
    } else { // This section does not work correctly.**
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("invalid operation")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
} else {
    exit();
}
?>
```

The initial approach doesn't cater for the scenario when they have the same value